# Kinematic Arrive Algorithm in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I am beginner at coding and I am testing out Kinematic Arrive Algorithm in Unity. I keep getting a error message saying

> Assets/Scripts/PlayerMovement.cs(24,31): error CS0103: The name 'LeftPoint' does not exist in the current context

How do I fix it?

`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private Transform trans;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rb;
    [SerializeField] private Transform target;
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody Rigidb;


    private float maxSpeed;
    private float radiusOfSat;

    void Start () {
        maxSpeed = 5f;
        radiusOfSat = 2f;
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        //an edit block of code from the original program
            Vector3 towards = LeftPoint.point - transform.position; //gets the distance from the mouse coordinates
            transform.LookAt(new Vector3(LeftPoint.point.x, transform.position.y, LeftPoint.point.z)); //tells the "sphere" object to look at the hit location
            if (towards.magnitude > radiusOfSat) //rotation and movement
            {
                towards.Normalize();
                towards *= maxSpeed;
                Rigidb.velocity = towards;
            }
    }
}
```

`

I was expecting my code to work but it seems that this one error keeps popping up

Comment: Where did you declare 'LeftPoint'? Can't find it in that code.

Comment: If you are going to use full-time kinematics then it is pointless to use a rigid body. I suggest you read-up on the work of [Craig Reynolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craig_Reynolds_(computer_graphics)), creator of _[Boids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boids)_, published in SIGGRAPH relating to [steering behaviours using classic kinematics](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/gdc99/).  Craig's [home page](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/).

Comment: [That](https://github.com/codemusket/kinematic-arrive/blob/master/Assets/KinematicArrive.cs) implementation of Steering Behaviour is way too short to be accurate.  See Craig's original code.  Also, it uses RBs.

Comment: Where _is_ `LeftPoint` defined?